# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 Login iphone (work Execution app) issue

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am using maximoAnywhere 7.6 version (Work Execution App). But i can't able to login my application. When i try to login application in iphone i got below that error. Kindly someone advice me.

error : 
BMXAA0024E - The action READ is not allowed on object SYNONYMDOMAIN. Verify the business rules for the object and define the appropriate action for the object.
oslc:statusCode : 400

[maximo version details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6m7i.png)

Comment: BMXAA0024E - The action ADD is not allowed on object [OBJECT_NAME].
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21623779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your user doesn't have access to any Sites.  Follow this technote..

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21659386